# 403 forbidden : You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server Port 443

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have installed the certificate but when I try to access the url with https it gives me 403 forbidden error, but when I try to use it with http it is working fine.

I have installed the certificate in /etc/ssl/certs/ and I have following files:

1. test.key
2. test.ca-bundle
3. test.crt

In apache I have placed .conf file in

1. /etc2/apach2/sites-available/test.com.conf
2. /etc2/apach2/sites-enable/test.com.conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcoredemo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcoredemo-access.log common
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://test.com/"
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/app>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@test.com
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/app

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.ca-bundle
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.key

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/app>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The website is create using .net core.

I don't know what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by specifying the correct DocumentRoot folder.
I was pointing to the wrong folder.

After I change the value for Document root in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf` file.